# I want to extract some specific data from json on React native

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, fetch, nsfetchrequest

I want to print some specific data like "area" or product id etc without using state

```
fetch('https://punjabfoodhub.in/app/reg.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      'item_id':ids,
      'func':'item_data',
    })
  }).then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => {

    this.setState(state => ({ item_data: state.item_data.concat(json) }) );
      console.log(json.area);

  }).catch((err) => { console.log(err);
});
```

**My json obbject is**

```
{
  "area": "Prantij",
  "branch_add": "Prantij,
  Toll-Plaza ",
  "branch_id": "1",
  "charge": "30",
  "name": "Jenil Chavda",
  "pin": "380004",
  "u_id": "6",
  "user_add": "Jeuwjsh jsjehsh shshw. Usjshshs"
}
```

But when I print **json.area** console show me a **undefined**

how can I solve this ?

Comment: What does `console.log(json);` print?

Comment: @WillWalsh yes json was printed successfully

Comment: this is a result of console.log(json) =  {"area": "Prantij", "branch_add": "Prantij, Toll-Plaza ", "branch_id": "1", "charge": "30", "name": "Jenil Chavda", "pin": "380004", "u_id": "6", "user_add": "Jeuwjsh jsjehsh shshw. Usjshshs"}

Comment: Are any of the other keys in the JSON accessible? Try, for example, `console.log(json.branch_add);` and see if that shows correctly

Comment: One issue I can see is your `setState` callback is incorrectly formatted. It should be without the parentheses around the object, such as `this.setState(state => { item_data: state.item_data.concat(json) });`.